The Gauss integral formula MathCad Prime
tell me how to solve the integral of the Gauss formula in mathcad Prime? I went to look, found the methods of rectangles, sim., but not Gauss.
Therefore, I decided to ask who can know how to solve the integral like this: (1+x^5)^(1/2). a=-2; b=4; n=5.

It's off topic here to begin with. It is ambiguous Gauss did a lot of mathematics so he has more than one formula. The expression you specify doesn't have a, b or n as parameters. Your question is unanswerable as posed.
